# Add a column in R with season time

Tags: r

I have a dataset like thatI want to add a column with season time like this:

| Month | Year | Region | Season |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | 2019 | NY | Winter |
| February | 2019 | NY | Winter |
| March | 2019 | NY | Spring |
| September | 2019 | NY | Fall |

How can I do a code in R that automatically add a column where all January, February and December are Winter, all March, April and May are Spring and so on.

Thanks a lot for helping

season <- c(data,  Spring = "March", Spring = "April")

Comment: Hi, have you tried to merge your datasets? Like `merge(df1, df2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R you could do:

```r
df1$Season <- c('Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall')[
  1 + (match(df1$Month, month.name) %/% 3) %% 4]
```

Which results in:

```
df1
#>       Month Year Region Season
#> 1   January 2019     NY Winter
#> 2  February 2019     NY Winter
#> 3     March 2019     NY Spring
#> 4 September 2019     NY   Fall
```

(Using akrun's reproducible data)

Answer (score 2):

We can create a keyvalue dataset and do a join

```
library(dplyr)
keydat <- tibble(Month = month.name, 
   Season = rep(c("Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter"), 
      c(2, 3, 3, 3, 1)))
df1 <- left_join(df1, keydat)
```

-output

```
df1
      Month Year Region Season
1   January 2019     NY Winter
2  February 2019     NY Winter
3     March 2019     NY Spring
4 September 2019     NY   Fall
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Month = c("January", "February", "March", "September"
), Year = c(2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L), Region = c("NY", "NY", 
"NY", "NY")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```